# How to get header values in Module.php?

Tags: php, header, zend-framework2

I am using Zend-Framework 2 and I want to access request headers in the `Module` for authentication purpose. How can I access the header in `module.php`?

I have tried this all

```
$headers = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders();
$headers = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('userId');
$headers = $this->getRequest()->userId;
$headers = $_SERVER['HTTP_LOGIN'];
```

I have also tried this

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
```

It's working but I need something else 
How to get it in `module.php`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A very dirty solution just to show you how to get access to your request headers. I would NOT recommend attaching authentication to this directly.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $headers = $event->getRequest()->getHeaders();
    var_dump($headers);
}
```

I would rather suggest attaching a listener to your `EventManager` on `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` event and take it from there.

You can easily pull the `Request` object from your `MvcEvent` with the `getRequest()` method inside your custom `Authentication` listener.

Check the [`ZF2 documentation` for details](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/tutorial.eventmanager.html) on the `EventManager` and attaching listeners.